# How do I mark the maximum and minimum limits in an animation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, octave, matlab-figure, scilab

I am programming an animation that represents the pressure shock wave and the resulting oscillations along the pipeline due to a sudden closing of the valve.

I can generate an animation similar to the one shown in the link:https://www.mathworks.com/help/hydro/ug/sscfluids_water_hammer.html.
I also want the maximum and minimum limits to be marked.

Comment: do you mean how to constrain the axis to a particular range throughout the animation?

Comment: Are you using MATLAB, Octave, or Scilab? They are different languages and solutions may be incompatible, please remove the unrelated tags (as requested in the tag descriptions for MATLAB and Octave)